# How combine 2 arrays of pandas, by common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. In both the two columns _a and _b. In df1, both columns are filled.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'_a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'_b':[3,4,5,3,3,3,9]})
df1

    _a  _b
0   1   4
1   3   9
2   4   3
3   2   5
```

In df2 only column _a is filled in another order. I need fill column _b in analogy with df1. In the end, it should look like this:

```
    _a  _b
0   4   3
1   3   9
2   1   4
3   2   5
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *you need to fill* ummm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways that I see it could be done

First. Use an index

```
temp_df = df1.set_index('_a')
df2['_b'] = temp_df.loc[df2['_a'], '_b']
```

Second. Join the dataframes

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2['_a'], df1, on='_a', how='left')
```